# How to add inline reply to 'notification' firebase message?

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

Now our servers sends `FCM` messages with "notification" type to the `Android` devices.
Is it possible to add `Inline` Reply (as described [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#direct)) action to notifications without resorting to the "data" type messages and handling notifications in the app?

Comment: What ended up being your solution?

Comment: There' was no way at the time, I'm unsure about current situation.

Comment: I can't understand what is your question. Do you want to reply to notification send from server?